# Java based, i cant find where i am going wrong in my code

Tags: java, jgrasp

Yes this is an assignment for school! so no answers please just a direction to work from :)

This code is supposed to get the day of the week, set the day and print the day. Also it needs to increment the day by one and return the next day, decrease the given day by one and return the previous day, then increment the day by a user given amount and return what day it will be in x days.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public  class MyDay
{
private int tempDays;
private String day;

  public String toString()
  {
     return (day);
   }

//Creates the method setDay, Uses switch statements to determine the day.     
   public void setDay(int tempDay)
   {
   String day;

     switch (tempDay){
     case 1: day= "Sun";
        break;
     case 2: day= "Mon";
        break;
     case 3: day= "Tues";
        break;
     case 4: day= "Wednes";
        break;
     case 5: day= "Thurs";
        break;
     case 6: day= "Fri";
        break;
     case 7: day= "Sat";
        break;
        }
     return (day);         
    }

 //Returns the day as a string.        
    public Day setName(String day)
    {
     day = tempDay;        
     return day;
    }

//Creates the method printDay, returns the string day.
    public void printDay()
    {      
     return (day);
     }

//Creates the method nextDay, Determines the next day.
   public void nextDay()
      {  
         nextDay=(tempDay+1)%7; 
         tempDay(nextDay);
         printDay();
      }

//Creates the method lastDay, Determines the previous day.        
   public void lastDay()
      {        
        lastDay=(tempDay-1)%7;     
        tempDay(lastDay);
        printDay(); 
      }

//Creates the method getDay, Determines the next day it will be based on the     users input.
   public void getDay()
      {
      static Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
      int x=0;
      int y=0;
         System.out.println("The next number you will be prompted to enter will return\n"+
                            "what day it will be in that many days.");            
         System.out.println("Enter a number using numeric keys only.");
         x= console.nextInt();
         y = day +(x);
         Day = y %7;
         tempDay(getDay);
         printDay();
      }

//Allows Day to be minpulated.
   public day()
      {
         tempDay(0);
      }

//converts Day into a string.
   public day (int tempDay)
     {
         tempDay(day);
     }


   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   //Import Scanner as imput device.
     static Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter the day you wish to set.");
  System.out.println("Enter 1 for Sunday\n"+"Enter 2 for Monday\n"+"Enter 3 for Tuesday\n"+
                        "Enter 4 for Wednesday\n"+"Enter 5 for Thursday\n"+"Enter 6 for Friday\n"+
                        "Enter 7 for Saturday");
    tempDay= console.nextInt();

    Day myDay = new Day(tempDay);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Today is: ");
    myDay.printDay();

    System.out.println("Tomorrow is: ");
    myDay.nextDay();

    System.out.println("Yesterday was: ");
    myDay.lastDay();

    System.out.println("In "+ x +"day(s), it will be: ");
    myDay.getDay();

   }
}
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g MyDay.java

MyDay.java:69: error: illegal start of expression
          static Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
          ^
MyDay.java:83: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
       public day()
              ^
MyDay.java:89: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
       public day (int tempDay)
              ^
MyDay.java:98: error: illegal start of expression
     static Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
     ^
4 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: "return type required" -- Have you tried fixing this on your own? I'd recommend taking a shot at it.

Comment: You can't declare a `static` local variable

Comment: yes @Vulcan i got it down from 48 errors to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages do explain the problems, once you get used to them:

The first and fourth errors are because you are declaring something static inside a method, which doesn't make sense. Just remove the `static` keyword.

The second and third are because your method doesn't have a return type - it must be `public void foo()`, `public String foo()`, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyDay.java:69: error: illegal start of expression
static Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Local variables cannot be static in Java. Just drop the `static`.

```
MyDay.java:83: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
public day()
```

You need to declare a return type for each method. If it does not return anything, use `void`:  `public void day()`.